# Will the universe end in a big crunch?

Tags: cosmology, universe, gravitational-waves

Someone posted this to my question on QUORA.

> Einstein's theory of relativity can be explained through the interactions of gravitational wave theory. Time dilation and length contraction can both be interpreted as results of the expansion and contraction of gravitational waves. When an object is moving at near light speed, it must be producing a huge amount of gravitational waves. An observer looking at the speeding object will see a distorted image caused by the expansion or contraction of gravitational waves.
>
> Time slows down or decreases because the distance is increased by the gravitational wave during the expansionary period. Length contraction is explained by the shortening of space-time during the contractionary period of the gravitational wave. The trough of the wave is located at the actual moving object itself while the crest is just in front of the object. However, once the gravitational wave finally hits the border of the universe, it will just permanently expand the space-time and therefore the universe.
>
> When the formation of gravitational waves start dissipating due to the lack of gravitational interactions, the universe will collapse on itself and restart the cycle of the Big Bang. However, gravitational waves will only stop being generated when all the matter in the universe combines into a super dense object/nucleus or SDN. Therefore, the maximum lifetime of a universe can be determined by how long until all the mass in it forms into one nucleus.

Can someone read this (its very short) and the part where he concludes the universe will end in a big cruncch and tell me if its valid?

Comment: There is little point in posting a OneDrive link for people who don't have a OneDrive account. You need to edit your question to include all relevant information.

Comment: i edited it with the conclusion he posted

Comment: The response to your question is complete nonsense.

Comment: what? do you mean that his reasoning is complete nonsense?

Comment: This is one of those "My Theory of the Universe" pieces that people with no mathematical background generate because it superficially sounds like it *might* be plausible if the reader knows little or no physics. Show us the maths.

Comment: the guy is apparently a nobel prize nominee. name is william guo. here is the link to my quora question. you will see his answer below with the link he provides to his short little writing. https://www.quora.com/How-will-space-expand-forever-if-there-is-a-constant-amount-of-energy-in-space

Comment: His reasoning is complete nonsense. I could claim to be a Nobel nominee as well. That wouldn't make it true.

Comment: Wow. Every single sentence in that quoted passage is either false or ["not even wrong"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Not_even_wrong).  I wish I had a pet gerbil so that I could say "My pet gerbil understands relativity better than that guy". :)

Comment: But to answer your question, modern cosmology (since the 1990s or so) considers Big Crunch scenarios to be **extremely** unlikely because the expansion of spacetime has been observed to be accelerating. The exact mechanism for this acceleration is still a mystery, but [dark energy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dark_energy) is a popular candidate.

Comment: It is total nonsense. He should be called out in Quora, if they have a mechanism. Or if not. Each phrase is nonsense: 1) the interactions of gravitational wave theory 2) expansion and contraction of gravitational waves 3) when ...moving at near light speed ...producing ....gravitational waves 4) time slows down because the distance is increased..5)contraction army period of the gravitational wave.   Etc. He is probably nobody. In any event this post should be closed, it is asking about some nonsense somebody asked somewhere else. It is not mainstream physics, nor physics, a waste of time

Answer (score 2):

This answer is not sound. At least, it is completely over my head and I can't really make sense of it.

However, it is extremely unlikely to be true, and to find out why, I would suggest you read the story of an *actual* Nobel Laureate who thought (as most people did in the early 1990s) that the expansion of the universe should be slowing down, possibly to revert towards a big crunch scenario. This particular Nobel Laureate worked out detailed and ingenious measurement schemes to confirm his research community's hunch that the [deceleration parameter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deceleration_parameter), which defines how the scale factor in the [FLRW universe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friedmann%E2%80%93Lema%C3%AEtre%E2%80%93Robertson%E2%80%93Walker_metric) varies with time, was positive.

He found he was wrong.

He spent months looking for his mistake in his data processing. When at last he conceded that there was no mistake, his observation was the first confirmation that the deceleration parameter was, in fact, negative and the first strong indication that the cosmological constant was positive (an accelerating expansion is either owing to a positive cosmological constant or exotic dark matter whose identity we so far have no idea of). His name is [Brian Schmidt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brian_Schmidt) and his [Nobel Lecture](https://www.nobelprize.org/nobel_prizes/physics/laureates/2011/schmidt-lecture.html) tells you the tale of his discovery that the big crunch is highly unlikely. Even better: his story is definitely not over my head and I think you will find it much more readable and understandable than your quoted answer.